# Ajax request multiple data info

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm going crazy over this script, i'm trying to het this working by when some one click on a button then with ajax fetch data from another URL then fill form inputs with the fetched data can any one help please 
   my code look like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $("#getmetaData").click(function(){

            var element = $(this);



            var url = $("#url").val();
            var dataString = 'url='+ url ;
            //alert(dataString); 
            if(url=='http://')
            {
            alert("Please Enter URL to fetch Meta Data");
            }
            else
            {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="images/loader.gif" >');

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "fetch-metadata.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){

            $("#title").val(data);
            $("#description").val(data);
            $("#keywords").val(data);
            $("#flash").hide();

            }
            });

            }
            return false;});});
```

Comment: tip:var element = $(this); this is not used in anywhere, You can check you query in your Ajax file

Comment: can you show code of `fetch-metadata.php` ?

Comment: Use firebug or google chrome inspector to track your ajax requests. See whether your request successfully returns a desired response.

Comment: there is no any error in the code, if fetch-metadata.php does not returns any error, see it in firebug debugger in firefox or in google chrome press **F12**; and if you want to put different data in `#title, #description, #keywords, #flash` different fields, then use `datatype:JSON` or **XML**, its your choice. refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and see **datatype** concept.

Answer (score 0):

If you see no error, which I am guessing is the case, it means your request is failing. Since you have no `error` function, when your request fails, your jQuery code will do nothing.

Add something like this to your `$.ajax` object argument:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // now you can set a breakpoint or log textstatus/errorThrown
},
```

Answer (score 0):

As per HackedByChinese's answer I would add an error callback function.

Also, in your success callback function you are simply using the 'data' variable without doing anything with it. Depending on the format of the response from 'fetch-metadata.php' I think you'll need to do something first. It's either XML in which case you'll need to parse it. If its json you can use object dot notation to reference it's properties.

Lastly, I'd use something like Firebug to look at the request and response for this Ajax request to make sure it's being processed and not returning a 404 or 500. Assuming its returning a valid response, using Firebug you can look at the response to see the raw data that is being returned to your js.

Hope this helps